# Laravel Query Default Value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a `categories` table. It has many relations (attributes, brands, products, parent categories, etc.). This table is holding `platform` categories like *eBay* and *Amazon*.

So I want to set a default value to my `requests`.

For example, I want to get a product's `category` if I don't set a value for a platform, a model must return the product's selected amazon category/categories.

Is there an easy way for this in Laravel? There is many query already written. I'm just trying to come up with the best and fastest solution.

If it is important, I'm using the latest Laravel 8.x version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer by changing the question. Sorry for this. I adding solution for someone can't find the true search terms like me;

try this way : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes